# Get hyper link from a SharePoint list column

Tags: javascript, list, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, hyperlink

I want to get the hyperlinks from a column of a SharePoint 2010 List. Right now the code gives me the hyperlink and the description concatenated together.
`

```
$(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
        content = new Object(); //get new object
        content.title = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
        content.url= $(this).attr("ows_Url");`
```

The content.url gives me "http://www.example. ca,%20http://www.example. ca". I have tried split and then the URL doesn't work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I'm understanding you correctly, split should work...  here's an encapsulated example:

```
<a id="yourlinkId">link</a>
<script>
var url = "http://www.example.ca,%20http://www.example.ca";
var n = url.split(",%20");
var a = document.getElementById("yourlinkId");
a.href = n[0];
</script>
```

combine that with your code and you end up with something like:

```
$(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
content = new Object(); //get new object
content.title = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
var url = $(this).attr("ows_Url");
var n = url.split(",%20");
content.url = n[0];
```